# Java Swing Nested JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My application needs to display the data from a very complex database, which has tables with primary key and foreign keys . Please guide me how to display this data in the  Java Swing nested JTable . Need to  display the data in the nested and collapsible format . For the reference purpose I have attached a  sample picture.

[image: Sample pic]

Comment: I am not aware of any Swing component that will allow you to do that. The closest you might come is a "tree table", but even that implementation fixes the columns that are displayed. However it will allow you to expand/collapse rows in the table.

Comment: Unless you have a link to this Swing nested JTable, you could display 3 separate JTables in your GUI.  You could have the Employee JTable on the left. and the Salary and WorkDays JTables on the right, one atop the other.  Since the Salary and WorkDays JTables would likely have only a few records, they wouldn't take up much space.

Comment: I suspect it comes from http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/grid/HierarchicalTable.html. Googling Jidesoft Hierarchical table images seems to bring up very similar stuff. But its paid software. Who has enough time to make something similar? If I wasn't away from Java for 6 years or so id give it a go lol miss the old days when I had time and thought java was the be all and end all

Comment: Lol actually found a github link which shows an example and seems to even have references to older jide libs 2.8.6. Not sure how the licensing works but here's the link for fun https://github.com/sramepa1/IndepModExporter/blob/master/libs/jide.2.8.6/examples/G8.HierarchicalTable/HierarchicalTableDemo.java. Reverse engineering anyone? 